# Is it possible to delete something with a HTTP GET request?

Tags: http, get

Is it possible to delete something with a HTTP GET request? Or get something deleted as a result of a HTTP GET request?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, you just have to handle the request correctly.

Let's assume your server side language is PHP (but it's basically the same in all server-side-languages):

- You make an XMLHttpRequest (a.k.a. AJAX request) or a GET request via a form with the parameters you want to check: f.e. `index.php?action=delete&id=123`
- in your PHP script you check the $_GET values of `action` and `id` (and probably user session values to verify that your user is logged in)
- execute a MySQL `DELETE FROM ...` statement in your PHP file or delete whatever you want to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but a really really bad idea, given the definition of GET in the HTTP specification.